# How do I put a viewPager with fragments inside of another viewPager with fragments?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I am trying to put a viewPager at the home tab in my app so the user can scroll through Pictures/Videos while being able to switch tabs in the parent viewPager.I have the swipe disabled for the parent tab. Currently the home page follows through all the other tabs and when I am on the home page the pictures in the child viewPager don't display only the test video but I can swipe through the empty slots.

MainActivity.cs

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        BottomNavigationView navigation = 
        FindViewById<BottomNavigationView>(Resource.Id.navigation);
        navigation.SetOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        //FragManager
        fm = this.SupportFragmentManager;

        //Page Change Adapter Setup
        MPA = new MasterPagerAdapter(fm, GetFragmentsMP());

        viewPagerNav = FindViewById<CustomViewPager>(Resource.Id.PageNav);
        viewPagerNav.disableScroll(true);
        viewPagerNav.Adapter = MPA;

        //Adapter
        Adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(fm, GetFragments());

        FrameLayout container = FindViewById<FrameLayout> 
        (Resource.Id.Frame);

        View view = View.Inflate(this, Resource.Layout.MainPage, 
        container);

        viewPager = view.FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.UserPicture);
        viewPager.Adapter = Adapter;

    }
```

MainActivity.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:actionBarNavMode="tabs"
tools:menu="navigation">

<FameAndroid.CustomViewPager
    android:id="@+id/PageNav"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:translationZ="1dp"/>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
</android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>

<Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:translationZ="3dp">

<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/refreshButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"/>

<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/reportButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_gravity="right"/>
</Toolbar >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:translationZ="4dp"/>
```

MainPage.axml (One of the Parent Page Fragments)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/containerMainPage"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/UserPicture"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>

  <ImageButton
android:id="@+id/likeButton"    
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
   />

<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/followButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why would you do something so complex?

Comment: @G.hakim It would be something like the Instagram or Facebook app.

Comment: Those are not two viewpagers my friend

Comment: @G.hakim I have one viewpager on MainPage.axml and one on MainActivity.axml

Comment: Since your parent ViewPage can't scroll, why not just replace it with a few fragments, and then use ViewPage within the Fragment ,and the code doesn't show what the problem is, so you need to give the code of adapter and fragment